# Undefined property: Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository::$verbos

Tags: composer-php

Trying to install a simple repository using composer (composer require vimeo/vimeo-api ^2.0)

And I can't seem to get it work.

Here's the error

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


  [ErrorException]                                                                      
  Undefined property: Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository::$verbose  


Exception trace:
 () at /Users/kevin/Documents/projects/hy/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:68
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at /Users/kevin/Documents/projects/hy/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:68
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository->initTags() at /Users/kevin/Documents/projects/hy/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AssetVcsRepository.php:44
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AssetVcsRepository->initialize() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php:185
 Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository->getPackages() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:104
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->addRepository() at /Users/kevin/Documents/projects/hy/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/Util.php:60
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\Util::addRepositoryInstance() at /Users/kevin/Documents/projects/hy/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/Util.php:39
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\Util::addRepository() at /Users/kevin/Documents/projects/hy/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AbstractAssetsRepository.php:140
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository->whatProvides() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:204
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:193
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:164
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromPackage() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:353
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->getRulesFor() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:217
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:475
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Installer.php:229
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:228
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->doUpdate() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php:185
 Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:245
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:835
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:185
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:267
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:106
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:61
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer.phar:24
```

I've tried using composer update, I've tried deleting the fxp/composer-asset-plugin and re-installing. Nothing seems to work.

In addition this is a Yii 2 app.

Per request I'm adding the composer.json into this.

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [

     ],
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.15",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "*",
        "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-colorinput": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "@dev",
        "m35/thecsv": "^1.0",
        "aweber/aweber": "^1.1",
        "sammaye/yii2-mailchimp": "*",
        "nickcv/yii2-mandrill": "*",
        "ofat/yii2-yashop-ses": "*",
        "frostealth/yii2-aws-s3": "@stable",
        "drewm/mailchimp-api": "^2.1",
        "ruskid/yii2-stripe": "*",
        "drewm/drip": "^0.6.0",
        "linslin/yii2-curl": "*",
        "braintree/braintree_php": "^3.17",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-timepicker": "*",
        "yii-dream-team/yii2-timezone-picker": "^0.1.0",
        "bryglen/yii2-sendgrid": "*",
        "mailgun/mailgun-php": "^1.8",
        "boundstate/yii2-mailgun": "*",
        "omnilight/yii2-vuejs": "^1.0",
        "jacobbennett/sendyphp": "^1.3",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "^2.0",
        "vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "*",
        "froala/yii2-froala-editor": "^2.7",
        "marqu3s/yii2-summernote": "dev-master",
        "himiklab/yii2-recaptcha-widget": "*",
        "activecampaign/api-php": "^2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "*",
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "^0.6.6",
        "kartik-v/yii2-slider": "*",
        "miloschuman/yii2-highcharts-widget": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.26",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev",
        "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "~1.1",
        "uploadcare/uploadcare-php": "^2.2"

    },




    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more details, like the content of `composer.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in the repository for `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`, it has seen some updates for the property `$verbose` which is no longer available in current Composer versions. You should update that package.

As it is not listed in your `composer.json`, some other package seems to require it. And to update the asset plugin, you probably need to update that other package too - check through `composer why fxp/composer-asset-plugin` which other plugin is responsible for this

Comment: I commented out those lines that had that property and it went through. Not sure if that's the right call here but it seemed to work. Hope things don't break 

Comment: Sorry, but that is not a good idea. Reinstalling that plugin will undo those changes again